# Getting data from POST request

Tags: ajax, vue.js, symfony3.x

I'm trying to update some data of my User Entity using AJAX request with VueJS-Ressource.

Here is my AJAX request:

```
           this.$http.post('/profile/edit', {
               description: this.description
           }).then(response => {
               console.log(response);
           }, response => {
               console.log(response);
           });
```

Here is the controller where I receive this AJAX request:

```
/**
 * @Route("/edit", name="profile_edit")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 */
public function profileEditAction(Request $request) {
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        /* @var User $user */
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $description = $request->request->get( 'description');

        if (isset($description)) {
            $user->setDescription($description);
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush($user);
            return new Response('Updated User description with success !');
        }

        return new Response('No description parameter found');
    }
    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
}
```

My issue is that every time I'm trying to get a parameter from my request using `$request->request->get('PARAMETER_NAME')`, it return a null value.

Whereas I display my request from my browser, I clearly sees that i'm sending something:

Full AJAX Request: https://i.gyazo.com/825ea438b09e4df8d8287555a1c841a6.png

I hope someone could help me with this, thanks you !

Comment: `var_dump( $request->request->all()  )` and see what you get.

Comment: You are sending JSON (Content-Type header); PHP does not populate $_POST when you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try posting the data as **FromData** (so that Content-Type is sent as `multipart/form-data`).

In VueJS, do this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('description', this.description);

this.$http.post('/profile/edit', formData)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    }, reason => {
        console.log(reason);
    });
```

Make sure in *Dev Tools -> Network* you see the sent data as **Form Data** (not as **Request Payload** ).

On server do `var_dump( $request->request->all() )` and see what `request` contains.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer @abdul-wahab, it works perfectly now !